# file reading issue

Tags: android, file-handling

i wanna read file in an other activity but i made it in another activity. I made it like this:

```
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

but reading like this:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new openFileInput("config.txt");
```

but this is not recognizing "openFileInput" and asking to make another class or something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `new`, you're not creating a new instance, you're invoking a method:

```
FileInputStream fstream = openFileInput("config.txt");
```